# Find index of string in list based on part of the string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
foolist = ['123-asd', '234-asd', '345-asd']
```

I want to find the index of the string that contains '234'. At the moment I have this:

```
boollist = ['234' in i for i in foolist]
```

which would produce a list of True and Falses for each index for `foolist`.

Then to find the index, `[print(i) for i,j in enumerate(foolist) if j==True]`

This seems abit unecessary, does anyone have a more eloquent method of finding the index of a string in list based on a part of that string

Comment: `[i for i,j in enumerate(foolist) if '234' in j]` ?

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks for that, Cheerws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next` with a generator expression and split by a specific character to reflect the structure of your strings:

```
foolist = ['123-asd','234-asd','345-asd']

res = next(i for i, j in enumerate(foolist) if '123' in j.split('-')[0])  # 0
```

If there can be multiple matches, you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [i for i, j in enumerate(foolist) if '123' in j.split('-')[0]]  # [0]
```

For equality, you should use `j.split('-')[0]] == '123'` as your condition instead.

**Note on print within a comprehension**

It's good practice to avoid `print` in a list comprehension, as it will return `None`. You will notice that, while your terminal will print the indices it finds, you are also building a list of `None` items with length equal to the number of matches. For all intents, that list has no use.

If you are only interested in printing items, you can use a `for` loop with a generator expression:

```
for idx in (i for i, j in enumerate(foolist) if '123' in j.split('-')[0]):
    print(idx)
```

Comment: "...as it will return None" While I agree, I think that's not the reason. It may be perfectly fine to call functions returning `None` in a list comprehension, the bad-practice bit is using the list comprehension for side-effects and discarding the result.

Comment: @tobias_k, Thanks, that's what I *meant*, but you've described it more eloquently. I'll update with a bit more :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984323/find-index-of-string-in-list-based-on-part-of-the-string#comment90918071_51984323 is more concise, more general, and solves the task "I want to find the index of the string that **contains** '234'. ". Too bad it isn't a votable answer. This is also fine, though, for this example.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa, Have to be pedantic here, it really matters where you put the bold: "the index of **the string** that contains '234'". This implies there's only one string. In my opinion, a scalar is a better object type for a single item than a list.